# DrawString to Rectangle, how to manually jump to new line?

Tags: c#

When you DrawString to a Rectangle it wraps the text nicely within those bounds.

What I want however is to be able to jump to the next line within those bounds at will.
So I could write:
*This

is the content of a larger rectangle.*

An alternative would be to just use multiple DrawStrings (representing one line each, from a split string or similar) but I'm looking for a simpler more elegant way if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply put a newline (`\r\n`) in the string.

Comment: Ah. Well no wonder it didn't work. My keypress functionality doesn't pass on the \r and \n text values 'unhampered'. You are perfectly right of course.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  D'Oh, looks like you have got it answered while I was typing this up and looking through my code about NoWrap flags  =) Glad to see you figured it out.

---

Like SLaks stated you can force a newline in your text. It should just work if your text is already wrapping naturally.

I cannot recall having to anything special other than making sure NoWrap was not in the FormatFlags. This should not apply to you since it is already wrapping.